# The type reference cannot find a public type named 'TabItem'. Line 9 Position 44

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. Its a decompiled C# code. I am getting the following Warning message

> The type reference cannot find a public type named 'TabItem'. Line 9 Position 44.  on tabbarcontrol.xaml.

Would appreciate suggestions in figuring out the error with the following xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="UBotCoreUI.TabBarControl"

 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

 xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls;assembly=Wpf.TabControl">
```

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type r:TabItem}">

  <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="5,0"/>

  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0"/>

</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

  <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Red"/>

</Style>
```

```
TabItemMinWidth="150" TabItemMinHeight="25"

            TabItemMaxHeight="25" Control.VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Control.BorderThickness="0"

            TabItemNormalBackground="{DynamicResource tabInactiveColor}"

            TabItemSelectedBackground="{DynamicResource tabActiveColor}"

            TabItemMouseOverBackground="{DynamicResource tabMouseOverColor}">

<Control.BorderBrush>

  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">

    <GradientStop Color="#7F8286" Offset="0"/>

    <GradientStop Color="#7F8286" Offset="1"/>

  </LinearGradientBrush>

</Control.BorderBrush>
```

Comment: Getting error in this line <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:TabItem}">